# how to get the most recent date per category in a table?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the most recent date for every category. This is my table:

tables names:

```
threads table:
threadID
title
category
author
date_posted
post
last_author
last_reply
total_posts
isLocked
isSticky
```

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM threads
                               GROUP BY category
                               ORDER BY last_reply");
```

This gives me the date of the first row appearing in the table with that category. I want to be able to get the most recent date for that category not the first seen row. Thanks.

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: Your first query is nonsensical, and doesn't do what you claim. However your solution appears correct (although you won't know which thread belongs to which category). Consider either to submit and accept an answer, or delete the question. And for next time , please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the aggregation function `MAX()` like this:

```
SELECT Max(last_reply) as recent FROM threads
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY last_reply
```

<sub>*Answer added on behalf of OP*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

To choose the most recent date per category in the table and if the date is contained in the column `last_reply` then you can try the following query for the same:

```
SELECT category, Max(last_reply) as most_recent_date FROM threads GROUP BY category;
```